# cudnn 7 confliction problem in compiling tvm with cuda 10.0, ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, cuda, gpu, cmake

I am using ubuntu 18.04 (x64), I installed cuda 10.0 with cudnn 7.6 (as suggested by Nvidia) and nvidia driver 410. I am trying to build tvm-7.0 with cuda, but Im getting the following error:

```
    -- Configuring done
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:272 (add_library):
  Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target tvm_topi because
  files in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit
  directories:

    runtime library [libcudnn.so.7] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
      /usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64

  Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.


CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:271 (add_library):
  Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target tvm because files in
  some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit directories:

    runtime library [libcudnn.so.7] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
      /usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64

  Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.


CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:273 (add_library):
  Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target tvm_runtime because
  files in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit
  directories:

    runtime library [libcudnn.so.7] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
      /usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64

  Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.
```

I have no idea about the problem.

Comment: I have the same problem in installing mxnet with exactly same errors.

Comment: I see no errors, only warnings that you have some old versions of things leftover in some system library areas. Does anything not run?

Comment: Yes, exactly. There were leftovers of previous cudnn shared library. I removed them and its working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem does not create any error to stop installation. There are libraries from previously installed cudnn. to solve the warning, it is enough to go 
     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
and remove libcudnn.so.7.